# Manage QGIS layer table content within a plugin?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to embed a layer table in a plugin but it's not only for viewing but also for editing.

My current code below displays the content

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayerCache
from qgis.gui import QgsAttributeTableView, QgsAttributeTableModel

layer_a = iface.activeLayer()
cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer_a, 10000)
model = QgsAttributeTableModel(cache)
model.loadLayer()
new_view = QTableView()
new_view.setModel(model)

new_view.show()
```

When I activate editing mode for the layer, I'm able to get the caption and change content but it does not persist after a "Return" to validate.

It seems I wrongly expect the sync between my current table and the content attached to the layer. I suppose it's due to the cache.
Any idea how can I sync both QtableView (native and mine)? Inserting the view from the table could be also a solution but I'm not sure it's possible.